# Double downvote?

Tags: support

How does that happen?

[image: yeah it is spam]

6 views but 8 downvotes?

Comment: spam flagging probably by automated processes such as the Charcoal SmokeDetector system?  No way for us to really tell.

Comment: Hm I was flagging this as spam. but did not downvote.

Comment: Related question on SO meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258453

Comment: And, of course, there's always the possibility of caching: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Because I was so suprised I reload the page. at least I'm sure, I do that. : D.

Comment: A viewer can downvote, then flag as spam (or abusive) which gives an automatic downvote.  That is two downvotes for one view.